# Windows powershell 7 still looks old

Tags: windows, powershell

I'm trying to install new powershell for windows but it's still looks like normal version of it.
I got the pwsh from windows store, but also tried to install it other way
Without it it's hard to set up fonts for wsl and also looks bad :D
[old pwsh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rkou6.png)

I wanted to looks like this, with tabs and so one
[new one (pic from internet)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hLTqE.jpg)

Comment: You should look for "Windows Terminal"

Answer (score 1):

Not having tabs is not an issue with your Powershell version. In the second screenshot you have Powershell open via  [Windows Terminal](https://apps.microsoft.com/detail/9N0DX20HK701?hl=en-US&gl=US), which supports Powershell and multiple tabs.

Comment: the second pic is from the internet :)

Comment: @MackodaGama doesn't matter where it's from, it's still showing `pwsh.exe` hosted in Windows Terminal, as opposed to your "old"-looking screenshot of `pwsh.exe` hosted in the default Windows Console Host.

Comment: Also worth noting: Even with Windows Terminal present, you may additionally have to make it the default terminal (console) application in order for PowerShell (and other console applications) to open in it by default:
Run `Start-Process ms-settings:developers` and select `Windows Terminal` from the dropdown list in the `Terminal` entry.